# Replacing a line in a file after grep command

Tags: macos, shell, sed

I'm trying to replace a `0x1` to `0x0` in a file, I managed to get the line but I didn't manage to replace the string.

Here is the code:

```
grep -B 2 setSecure filePath | head -n 1
```

How can I proceed from here to change the string on the file? I'm using OS X, and I want to change the string only on this line.

Input File:

```
sometext
 .line 344
const/4 v1, 0x1

iput v1, p0, Lnagra/nmp/sdk/NMPVideoView;->mCurrentState:I

const/4 v1, 0x1

invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/view/SurfaceView;->setSecure(Z)V

    .line 344
const/4 v1, 0x1

iput v1, p0, Lnagra/nmp/sdk/NMPVideoView;->mCurrentState:I
sometext
```

Output:

```
const/4 v1, 0x1
```

Please note there is many lines that start with "const/4 v1, 0x1" in the file.

I need to change only the "0x1" above the "invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/view/SurfaceView;->setSecure(Z)V"

Comment: Please post samples in your post samples of input and output in code tags.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: @Blacky: did you mean `0x0` in your output?

Comment: nope, this is what I want to do, to change the 0x1 to 0x0 in the file, I only managed to get the correct line, but didn't managed to replace the string.

Comment: @Blacky, you should give proper samples to all your posts + try to encourage people by up-voting(if you think their posts are helpful only) and try to select a CORRECT answer too to close the thread properly.

Comment: I fix it, I don't understand why you need to write again.

Comment: Is there some way in which the patterns will appear? ie, will the `const/4 v1, 0x1` appear exactly 2 lines above the `invoke-virtual` or something?

Comment: Yes, look at my code, if  there is "setSecure" its 2 line above it.
The code above work  great for finding the line.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/const\/4 v1, 0x1/{prev=$0;$NF="0x0";val=$0;getline;print;getline;if($0 ~ /invoke-virtual {v0, v1}/){print val ORS $0} else {print prev};prev=val="";next} 1'  Input_file
```

In case you need to save output into Input_file itself then append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` to above code too.

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong but this code will change the string every time it find "const/4 v1, 0x1"?

Comment: look again on the question, "const/4 v1, 0x1" repeating in the file many times.
I want to change only the line that above "invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Landroid/view/SurfaceView;->setSecure(Z)V"

Comment: @Blacky, please check my EDIT and let me know on same? But since you have not shown much sample then as per your shown sample only I have written this code, check it out.

Comment: The code is working but still not perfect, the empty line between the "setSecure" to the "0x0" is gone, and the code removing the spaces from the start of the "0x0" line.
I would fix it myself but I don't really understand the code

Comment: @Blacky, let me add explanation now for same too.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use grep for this task, grep only print and not modify the file.
You can use awk.

```
awk -v seen='setSecure' -v search='0x1' -v rplt='0x0' -v lign=1 '
  NR<3 {
    a[NR]=$0
    next }
  $0 ~ seen {
    sub( search , rplt , a[lign] ) }
  {
    a[NR]=$0
    print a[lign]
    delete a[lign++] }
  END {
    for( i=lign ; i<=NR ; i++ )
        print a[i] }
' input
```

With sed

```
sed '1N;N;/setSecure[^\n]*$/bA;P;D;:A;s/0x1/0x0/;P;D' input
```

---

```
sed '
  1 
    N
# Always keep two lines in the pattern space
    N
# get a third one
# and search for your word
# if find jump to A
  /setSecure[^\n]*$/bA
# not find
# print the first line of the pattern space
    P
# delete it and start a new cycle
    D
  :A
# the word is find
# do the replacement
    s/0x1/0x0/
# print the first line of the pattern space
    P
# delete it and start a new cycle
    D
' input
```

If it's ok, you can add -i "" to replace the file

Comment: I looked on the output and it didn't work, looks like nothing happened.

Comment: You are right. must look more for sed. You can try this awk.

Answer (score 0):

Using your already working command to find out the line number, the following sed command will replace all occurrences of 0x1 to 0x0, on lines starting with 'const/4', if it appears at least 2 lines before a line containing 'setSecure'

```
$ for LN in $(grep -n -B 2 setSecure filePath | grep 'const/4' | cut -d '-' -f 1 ) ; do sed -i ${LN}s/0x1/0x0/g filePath  ; done
```

On Mac, following works :

```
$ for LN in $(grep -n -B 2 setSecure filePath | grep 'const/4' | cut -d '-' -f 1 ) ; do sed -i.bu ${LN}s/0x1/0x0/g filePath  ; done
```

Comment: This is what I'm getting:
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: What OS are you on ?

Comment: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4

Comment: Tested this on 10.12.6 , the only change I had to make was to add '.bu' to the -i flag of sed. ( I have updated the answer. )

Answer (score 0):

This is going to look a little ugly but is actually not terribly complicated. Using sed:

```
sed '1h; 1!H; $!d; x; s@\(const/4 v1, \)0x1\([^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*setSecure[^\n]*\n\)@\10x0\2@' filename
```

(pass `-i` to edit in-place after testing). This works by first reading the whole file into the hold buffer, then matching several lines at once:

```
1h    # If we're processing the first line, write it to the hold buffer
1!H   # if not, append it to the hold buffer
$!d   # If we're not at the end of the file, we're done with this line here.
x     # When we finally get here, we're at the end of the file, and the whole
      # file is in the hold buffer. Swap hold buffer and pattern space, so the
      # whole file is in the pattern space. 

# Then: apply transformation. The regex is somewhat ugly because of all the \ns,
# but all that's really happening here is that we match const/4 v1, 0x1 followed
# by two lines of which the second contains "setSecure", and then replace the
# 0x1 with 0x0.
#
# To understand it, consider that \n[^\n]*\n matches newline followed by non-
# newline characters followed by another newline, which is exactly one line.
# Similarly, \n[^\n]*setSecure[^\n]*\n matches a line 
s@\(const/4 v1, \)0x1\([^\n]*\n[^\n]*\n[^\n]*setSecure[^\n]*\n\)@\10x0\2@
```

Since you're using MacOS: MacOS by default uses BSD sed, which is limited in a number of ways. I think back in the day it had problems with `\n` in its code, so you may have to swap literal newlines in there for them. Although to be frank, if you're going to use sed under MacOS, it'd be least painful to just install GNU sed from homebrew.